# Connect flight from Berlin (Germany) to Palma (Spain) refusing us

Tags: uk, transit, transit-visas, connecting-flights

We bought connected flight from Berlin to Palma via London from Ryanair (third party, my trip). We checked on UK.gov website and it said with EU residence permit (Iranian citizen living in Germany) we don't require visa for transit. But now at the airport they are refusing to let us fly and say we need a visa. Is the information on the UK website inaccurate?

Comment: Is this a single reservation number or two separate ones? Ryan Air does sell connecting flights, but it's rare.

Comment: Is this London Stansted?

Comment: @Hilmar:  separate reservation numbers.

Comment: You didn't buy a connected flight. Ryanair does not sell those. Ryanair also extremely dislikes people booking via third parties.

Comment: @Krist van Besien: I dislike Ryanair too.

Comment: @Gigili I never fly Ryanair. And I also never (and neither should you) buy plane tickets from anybody but the airline itself.

Comment: @KristvanBesien This advice is a bit too general. There is nothing wrong with a reputable travel agent. Also, airline websites are often limited regarding which fares or routings their IT systems are able to sell, so using a travel agency (offline or online) can be needed in some cases.

Comment: @KristvanBesien I am reminded of the time I wanted to book a specific itinerary involving JAL and BA (both OneWorld) but neither BA's nor JAL's website would allow me to book it ... but Finnair (also OneWorld) did. So I booked a return ticket on Finnair's site that involved zero Finnair flights but two BA and three JAL.

Comment: @Jan: Meh, buying a cross-listed flight from a partner airline is IMHO not materially different to buying it from the original airline. Of course, you should always shop around to make sure you are not getting ripped off, but a partner airline is much less likely to screw up your reservation or charge an extortionate commission on the flight (as compared to using a travel agent).

Answer (score 28):

You have bought two separate tickets, Ryanair doesn't sell this connection. To be able to check in for the first flight you need to be allowed to enter the UK since that is you destination on the first ticket. From Ryanair's viewpoint your tickets aren't connected and your visit in the UK isn't transit.

The uk.gov site is correct, if the airline would let you fly to the UK the border agents would have let you through with an onward ticket.

Comment: We don't want to go through security or border control, we have no luggage to pick, we can go straight to transit and next flight. Why isn't it possible?

Comment: @Gigili It is possible but Ryanair doesn't allow you to. For example, your second flight might be cancelled and then Ryanair is stuck with a passenger in London that can't enter the country. It is a responsibility they don't want to take.

Comment: When the UK government says I don't need a visa, how could an airline tell me something else? I don't get it.

Comment: @Gigili Because you have two tickets with a stay in the UK between them. Ryanair doesn't care if this stay is two hours or two weeks, you must be able to enter the UK even if that isn't your plan. Again, what would happen if your second flight is cancelled?

Comment: Ryanair is a point to point airline. It doesn’t do connected flights, and its London hub is Stansted which has no airside transit https://www.stanstedairport.com/help/passenger-guides/connecting-flights/ Your booking is actually 2 completely separate flights: Berlin>London, clear UK Immigration, then exit UK for the London>Palma flight.

Comment: No airside transit at London Luton either.

Comment: @traveller, I don't care about Ryanair, I care about UK and its regulations. If it does allow me to transit without a visa, an airline can't deny that.

Comment: RyanAir isn’t exactly noted for its customer service. On arrival in the UK you will be clearing Immigration before proceeding to your next flight. The airline has no way of knowing for certain that you will board your onward flight on arrival in London, you are entering the UK and not transiting as far as the airline is concerned.

Comment: [The UK Government Online Q&A page](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y) returns a finding that a citizen of Iran needs a visa to enter the UK. Because your first flight lands in Stanstead, you must pass UK Immigration - as noted, there is no sterile airside transit at Stanstead. Ryanair is unfortunately correct here: your flight drops you into the UK, _and you are not eligible to enter the UK without a visa_. The UK is no longer part of the EU. What website said you could enter the UK with an EU residence permit?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Clearly, the OP is relying on his contention to be merely transiting, not on the ability to enter the UK. The exemption from the DATV requirement for EU residence permit holders is not tied to EU membership, similar exemptions exist, e.g. for US visas. Even when the UK was still in the EU, it was not possible to enter the country based solely on a residence permit in another EU country except, in limited cases, Ireland.

Comment: @Gigili In practice, they can. Gov.uk doesn't spell it out exactly but that rule is designed to help airlines (and especially BA) offer transit through the main London airports, no more and no less. Ryanair doesn't.

Comment: @Gigili The UK government allows airports and airlines to provide convenient airside transits with looser visa restrictions than normal; it is not an absolute right the government grants to passengers. Allowing airside transit (and, in RyanAir's case, allowing booked connections) requires significant extra effort from both airlines and airports, and so not all airlines and not all airports offer it.

Comment: @Gigili UK does allow transit without a visa, but only the legal definition of "transit" i.e. at equipped airports such as Heathrow, and the carrier not doing something to screw that up.  You are relying on the *colloquial* definition of "transit", which is not good enough.  And Ryanair is infamous for cock-ups like this and taking advantage of passengers.

Comment: So, since Ryanair holds the responsibility of returning the passenger to his point of departure (Germany), he will in practice have to be checked in for a German bound flight from the same airport where he is not allowed to check in and board a Spain bound flight? This is beyond ridiculous. Of course, Ryanair check in staff should have done their job and check his visa requirements beforehand, now they have to pay for their, and OPs, mistake.

Comment: @a20 That is why they check this at the point of departure (in Berlin), so that such situations don't arise. Remember also that these regulations are mostly intended to prevent people from arriving in country that don't have authorization to enter that country, avoiding a time consuming, costly deportation process.

Comment: @MarkJohnson yes, they are obliged to check passengers before allowing them to board. Clearly that did not happen here, or they were not aware of the rules.

Comment: @a20 You are misreading the situation. The OP states elsewhere that the **boarding staff** offered to reroute to another airport where a visa was not required.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Landside transit without visa is also allowed for Schengen common-format residence permit holders. But it does depend on whether your first separately ticketed airline allows you to board.

Answer (score 11):

The Berlin flight to Stansted airport enters the **Common Travel Area**, where others on the same flight could continue on to Ireland (or remain in the UK) or, as in your case, travel on to the **Schengen Area** (together with any domestic UK travelers starting their journey in Stansted).

Passengers from **all incoming flights** from outside of the *Common Travel Area* have to go through immigration together, after which the passengers continues on to their respective destinations.

The person I was traveling with (Canadian, with a German permanent residence permit) received a **leave to enter** for Ireland (which was checked again on arrival at Shannon airport).

For this (returning to the Schengen Area) you would have needed a UK transit visa.

> [Visa to pass through the UK in transit - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa)
> Apply for a Visitor in Transit visa if you’ll be going through UK border control but leaving the UK within 48 hours.

It is the **sole** responsibility of the passenger to ensure that they have the required documentation needed. The airlines are required to enforce any immigration regulations. Failing to do so would entail, for them, a heavy fine, which they may attempt to pass on to the passenger.

Comment: A Berlin>UK>Palma trip seems quite an odd routing to choose, especially with two separate tickets, when direct flights Berlin>Palma are available eg https://www.lufthansa.com/xx/en/flights/flight-berlin-palma+de+mallorca

Comment: Not sure I get you. Check "Transiting without a visa" here, you can see the answers given to the guide in the bottom of the page:  https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/iran/transit/somewhere_else/yes
I believe this is all about that the airline follows the rules for staying rather than transiting.

Comment: @Traveller Price? Ryanair sometimes offers extremely cheap tickets for people who don't care how long it takes, how far out of town the airport is or what time they have to get up at. I don't recall Lufthansa being famous for cheap flights...

Comment: @Anders No, it is about going through Border Control or not. In Heathrow (that has an airside transit area) a transit visa may not be required. But airports, such as Stansted, that don't have an airside transit area, you must go through immigration. *You should apply for a Visitor in Transit visa if you arrive on a flight **and will pass through immigration control before you leave the UK***.

Comment: @OscarBravo But don't forget to add the cost (and time) for the visa: **Visitor in Transit visa - £64** (and the price for a passport, if you don't have one)

Comment: @Oscar Bravo Cheaper than being denied boarding, and less risky than a self-transfer.. Plus UK border officials consider whether the individual is genuinely in transit to another country, meaning the purpose of their visit is to transit the UK and that the applicant is taking a *reasonable* transit route https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-transit-without-visa-scheme Ryanair holds all the cards here, in effect the OP has no recourse

Comment: @MarkJohnson "You should apply for a Visitor in Transit visa if you arrive on a flight and will pass through immigration control before you leave the UK" is this your advice is it from gov.uk somewhere?

Comment: @MarkJohnson_ The boarding staff told me there is one thing ahe could do and that was changing the airport, doe sit mean I could do the transit without going through boarder control if they changed the airport?

Comment: @Anders Yes, it is on the page of the link that you provided: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/iran/transit/somewhere_else/yes

Comment: @Gigili If that airport has an airside transit area (such as Heathrow), then yes with a Schengen residence permit no transit visa is required.

Comment: @MarkJohnson but it also mentions "Transiting without a visa". I would guess that Ryanair wouldn't have accepted a transit visa anyway.

Comment: @Anders Yes, it does meantion "Transiting without a visa", but from my understanding that applies to a **Direct Airside Transit visa (DATV) - £35**: *Apply for a Direct Airside Transit visa (DATV) if you’ll be changing flights in the UK and will not be going through UK border control.* This would work in Heathrow, but not Stansted. (Quote from link in my answer).

Comment: @Anders No, had the OP a **Visitor in Transit visa - £64** (or a valid *Standard Visitor visa*) then Ryanair would have no reason not to accept it for a flight through Stansted. That is what they were looking for at the airport in Berlin.

Comment: UK visa exemption for Schengen common-format residence permit holders allows them to pass passport control, including change of airports. But of course in this case Ryanair could make a case that they do not have enough information to ascertain the passenger's purpose.